# How to publish android application screenshots in landscape mode on android market?

Tags: android, android-market-filtering

I am new to Android Development. 
I just uploaded and published my application on Android Market i.e. Google Play Store.
I am going through a problem these days that i cannot upload my application screenshots in a landscape mode on Android Market. 
Can anyone help me out for this ?

Thanks in advance for your solutions or feedbacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Play's tip about screenshots on App Info page

> Full bleed, no border in art  You may upload screenshots in landscape
>   orientation. The thumbnails will appear to be rotated, but the actual
>   images and their orientations will be preserved.

So image are uploaded in portrait mode only. Take screenshot of rotated screen and while uploading turn the dimension to portrait (if their dimension is landscape i.e width is greater than height).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I tried this by changing the image and making the width greater than height, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: I tried it again just now and it's working. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

At first, rotate 90 degrees and upload 2 portrait images as required, then continue upload your landscape screenshots.

After all, delete your first 2 portrait screenshots

Answer (score 0):

Updating pixels to 2000x1000 solved my problem.